# For loop within SDE

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, feature-class

I have a list of SDE connection files in a folder in my computer. I can use arcpy.listWorkspaces("*", "SDE") to find the workspaces. But I then want to dig deeper into each of the SDE files and list the feature classes.

I tried:

```
sdeFiles=[]
listWorkSpaces=arcpy.ListWorkspaces("*", "SDE")
for sde in listWorkSpaces:
    arcpy.env.workspace=sde
    getFeatureClasses=arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    getFeatureClasses.sort()
    sdeFiles.extend(getFeatureClasses)
print sdeFiles
```

So when I print the sdeFiles list, it will list all the SDE feature classes in all the SDE files, but sometimes it will list them 6+ times, so it's duplicating it. 
I imported the list to excel and removed duplicates. It created 1514 duplicates and only 650 unique values. Frustrating!

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: So you're asking why multiple data connections might contain accesses to the same tables?

Comment: Turns out I was able to solve this on my own. Not sure if it's as pretty as it could be, but here it is:

import arcpy, itertools, sys, os
dirname="C:\\Users\\*myusername*\\AppData\\Roaming\\ESRI\\Desktop10.1\\ArcCatalog\\"
arcpy.env.workspace=dirname
listWorkSpaces=arcpy.ListWorkspaces("*", "SDE")
for FCitem in listWorkSpaces:
    print("SDE Dataset: "+FCitem[61:])
    arcpy.env.workspace=FCitem
    featureClassList=arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    featureClassList.sort()
    print featureClassList

I don't understand the comment formatting just yet...

Comment: You cannot format code in comments. Instead you should put your resolution as an answer, select the code and press Ctrl-K to format it correctly. Comments should be used to ask probing questions about a question, not for elaborating on the question or answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to list the unique values, modify as follows:

```
sdeFiles=[]
listWorkSpaces=arcpy.ListWorkspaces("*", "SDE")
for sde in listWorkSpaces:
    arcpy.env.workspace=sde
    getFeatureClasses=arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    sdeFiles.extend(getFeatureClasses)
sdeFiles = sorted(set(sdeFiles))
print sdeFiles
```